# Como actualizar array en AngularJS (Angular 1)?

Tags: angularjs

quiero actualizar un dato de un arreglo json

```
vm.lista...
for(var i=0; i<lista.length; i++){
 if(lista[i]=="inicio"){
    lista.nombre="cambiando de valor";
 }
}

<div ng-repeat="item in lista">
```

> no se ve los cambios, pero cuando aplico $scope.apply se actualiza,
>   esta bien que use apply? hay otra manera?

Comment: Una pregunta, la lista va tener los mismos campos?

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales claro los mismo campos solo quiero cambiar su valor de sus atributos

Comment: Buenas, podrías agregar el código completo del controller y el html? Gracias